# Anti-static drag strips benefits of earthing?

Tags: electrical, corrosion

I know this sounds like a stupid question but could an anti-static dragging strip have any benefits to a car attached to certain parts of a car in terms of galvanic corrosion or any other form of earthing benefits?

Background-I run a classic car that has a steel frame prone to corrosion I wondered whether attaching an anti-static drag strip or attaching the frame to the aluminium engine would have any benefits.(apart from the lack of static lol!!?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know if it would help with regular corrosion, but would have no effect on [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion). Galvanic corrosion happens when certain dissimilar metals come in contact with an electrolyte present. It has nothing to do with static electricity. As far as connecting the frame to the engine, it should already have that present. If not, get one, however again, it won't eliminate corrosion on the frame.

Comment: One of the curious reasons I came up with this idea was when cars went from having a positive to negative earth one of the side effects/benefits was reduced corrosion and I wondered if creating another ground to earth path could also have any effect?
Anyone any further ideas on it?

Answer (score 0):

It would have zero affect on corrosion. Once moisture and air hits steel, you have automatic oxidation. Galvalnic action is created when an electrolyte (water, salt water, etc) comes in contact with two dissimilar metals.

Comment: Galvanic corrosion happens to *certain* dissimilar metals. Like stainless and aluminum. Doesn't just happen between two random dissimilar metals.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it does occur to different degrees between any pair of dissimilar metals - even gold and platinum. However iron alloys are a bit anomalous, because "passive stainless" alloys are near one end of the galvanic potential spectrum and "active stainless" near the other end, along with mild steel and cast iron. For example mild steel vs copper corrodes the steel, but stainless steel vs copper corrodes the copper. See https://www.pemnet.com/design_info/galvanic-corrosion/ for more data.

Answer (score 0):

Static electricity will have minimal effect because the amount of charge is very small.  If you’ve ever tried electroplating you’ll know that a current of several amps takes a while to deposit a few microns of metal; similarly a momentary zap, or the equivalent charge leaked out over a period of time isn’t going to do much.  And there’s a 50% chance it will act to reverse any existing oxidation, depending on what surface you’re driving on.